# Route helpers in asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, assets, asset-pipeline

using Rails 3.1.0.rc4, I'm trying to access a route helper in a javascript file (event.js.erb in this case) and it seems like they are not loaded at that moment. When requesting the merged /assets/application.js file, I get:

```
throw Error("NameError: undefined local variable or method `events_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000001580010>:0x00000003191510>\n  (in /<...>/app/assets/javascripts/event.js.erb)")
```

Any idea how to access the route helper in there?

Comment: I am having this same issue in Rails 3.1 stable. Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

UPDATE: Now there is a gem that does this for you: [js-routes](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes)

---

The problem is that Sprockets is evaluating the ERB outside of the context of your Rails app, and most of the stuff you're expecting isn't there.

You can add things to your Sprockets context like so:

```
Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

That's all well and good, but getting the helpers that require an id to work is a little trickier. I'm going to use a technique called a [URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570):

```
var event_path = "<%= CGI.unescape event_path('{event_id}') %>";
```

which returns `/events/{event_id}` which you could render into a url using an object like `{ event_id: 1 }`. See SugarJS's [String#assign](http://sugarjs.com) method as example implementation of this. You could also [roll your own](https://github.com/lyconic/jquery.rest/blob/master/jquery.rest.js#L77) like I did.

Comment: Noob question, but how do you find the `MyRailsApp` path bit?

Comment: @MildFuzz It's the name you gave the project when you created it. Look in `config/application.rb` if you don't remember.

Comment: Is there a better way to do it? I use this `::Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_user_session_path`

Comment: @Nick `Rails.application` vs `MyRailsApp::Application` are basically equivalent here.

Comment: @AdamLassek Yes, except you don't need to remember what your app is called.

Comment: @Nick to be honest I can't imagine that ever being a problem.

Comment: @Nick although I do see the value for documentation purposes, you can give people working code instead of a fake namespace.

Comment: This answer should be updated to include @Nick's fix. It's actually really helpful to avoid stating the name of your application. Say you have to port the code elsewhere or extract it to an engine. You should avoid referencing your own application by name as much as possible.

Comment: @sidewaysmilk route helpers are very specific to your particular application by design. Using a generic reference is of limited usefulness.

Comment: AdamLassek: Respectfully, I disagree. Consider view helpers that take an object and generate a URL. Making it generic eases code reuse and encourages good code hygiene. Furthermore, it's more explicit and more obvious how the value is obtained. Also, we're talking about embedding Ruby in JavaScript. I can't tell you how many times I've reused JavaScript that I've written across applications. Finally, at least including @Nick's contribution as a "you might also try" footnote in your answer might help future knowledge seekers. I think it deserves a mention since it's the answer that helped me.:)

Comment: @sidewaysmilk I'd say the comments here already serve that purpose :) Plus if you're reusing route helpers on the backend, you'd be doing that via a Rails Engine, in which case the engine class will always be there, and Rails.application would no longer be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the file to views where it has access to the proper context, then pull it down to the client from a JS source tag.  Referring to MyRailsApp::Application.routes.url_helpers may not be the best if you are writing an engine.

Comment: You can do [EngineName]::Engine.routes.url_helpers