# Url in Ruby/Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use the same AJAX call to my routes.
How I set url??

**routes:**

```
put :sort, :path => 'activities/sort', :controller => 'activities'
put :sort, :path => 'articles/sort', :controller => 'articles'
```

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: 'activities/sort',  # I wanna change this line
            data: {ids:newOrder}, 
            dataType: "html",
            error: function()
            {
                alert('Positions has not been saved.');
                $('#sortable').sortable('cancel');
            }
         });
```

I thinking something like this:

```
url: <%= action: 'sort' %>
```

But it redirect to 'localhost:3000/sort' but I want 'localhost:300/current_controller/sort'

Answer (score 3):

Your route generates the following

```
sort PUT      /activities/sort(.:format)      activities#sort
```

As mentioned in **[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725629/route-helpers-in-asset-pipeline)**

> Sprockets is evaluating the ERB outside of the context of your Rails app

So, `.js.erb` files don't have access by default to the URL helper methods; they must be included explicitly.

```
<% 
  # at the top of your file somewhere
  url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
%>

// ...
url: <%= url.sort_path %>,
// ...
```

Comment: undefined local variable or method `sort_path' for main

Comment: This solution worked only in activities page. In articles page, the url is the same of activities page. `url.sort_path` get the first route with `sort`.. I need something to get current controller name.. `controller_name/sort`

Comment: Yeah, you need to learn to **[name your routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)**. Add `as: :sort_activities` and `as: :sort_articles` to the proper routes in `config/routes.rb` and then reference them as `sort_activies_path` and `sort_articles_path` in your `.js.erb` files.

Comment: But in this case I will need Copy and Paste my Ajax method for each route? Wanted to use only once

Comment: Sorry, your question is pretty poorly worded. I will post how I handle this in a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this:

```
def javascript_variables(variables = nil)
  @inline_js_variables ||= {}
  @inline_js_variables.merge!(variables) and return if !variables.nil?

  output = ''

  @inline_js_variables.each do |variable, value|
    output << "var #{variable} = #{value.to_json};\n"
  end

  output.strip.html_safe
end
```

You might put the above in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`. Then in your `ApplicationController`, you can put this at the top of the class.

```
helper :all
```

Now, in your action you can do something like

```
def your_activities_action
  javascript_variables({ ajax_route_path: sort_activities_path })
end

def your_articles_action
  javascript_variables({ ajax_route_path: sort_articles_path })
end
```

In your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` you can put the following in the `<head>`

```
<script>
  <%= javascript_variables %>
</script>
```

Finally, in your `.js` file you can use `ajax_route_path` in your `url` parameter.

```
url: ajax_route_path,
```

Based on this answer and my other one, you should be able to piece together what you're trying to accomplish. For example, if you need both `sort_activities_path` and `sort_articles_path` included in the same action

```
def your_articles_action
  javascript_variables({ ajax_activities_route_path: sort_activities_path,
                         ajax_articles_route_path:   sort_articles_path })
end
```

and then modify your Javascript file to use each accordingly *(for example, by wrapping the Ajax method in your Question in a function, accepting the route for `url` as an argument)*.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand your solution.. Do not have a way to simplify this? I'm imagining a solution of only one line..

Comment: I wanted to just specify the action, and the rails identify which controller is

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `/` in front, like so:

```
'/activities/sort'
```

Otherwise, it's going to use, as you said, `/current_controller/activities/sort` because without the `/` in front, the paths are relative rather than absolute.

Comment: this url is working, I just want change this URL Hard-code to ruby/rails language