# Rails Helpers in View - undefined local variable or method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have this Helper in my **ApplicationHelper**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def sort_url
    controller_name = params[:controller] 
    url = controller_name + '/sort' 
  end
end
```

And in **application.js.erb**

```
url: "<%= sort_url %>",
```

Error:

```
undefined local variable or method `sort_url'
```

Comment: Is it in `helpers/application_helper.rb` ? Can you use `sort_url` from a .html.erb file?

Comment: This is a poor way to solve the problem you're having in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998518/url-in-ruby-rails/11999325

Answer (score 1):

That is because the ApplicationHelper is only included in views by default.

The javascript file is not a view.

If you really want to use helpers in the view, you can use

```
<% environment.context_class.instance_eval { include MyHelper } %>
```

For more information on a related question, see: [Using a Rails helper method within a javascript asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451517/using-a-rails-helper-method-within-a-javascript-asset)