# erb in coffeescript (Rails 3.2.13)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, erb

I am using Rails 3.2.13.

After looking at some posts here, it looks like in order to use erb in CoffeeScript, your file just needs to have a `.js.coffee` extension, not `.js.coffee.erb` (weirdly).

However, I still cannot seem to get it to work. For example, I have the following in a `demo.js.coffee` file:

```
console.log '<%= root_url %>'
```

Which, after all processing, seems to produce:

```
(function() {
  console.log('<%= root_url %>');

  $(function() {});

}).call(this);
```

As you can see, the CoffeeScript is processed, but the erb isn't. What's going on?

Comment: change it to `.erb` and report back :-)

Comment: @Guy Changing it to `demo.js.coffee.erb` results in: `undefined local variable or method 'root_url'`. It's like `root_url` is not recognizable from within javascript assets...

Comment: I believe this answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725629/route-helpers-in-asset-pipeline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is confusing, in some cases the `.erb` extension is required and in some it is not. I've found that when dealing with coffee script files under the assets directory it is required, however, when within the views it is implied.

So in your case it should be called `demo.js.coffee.erb`

The second problem, is that the erb is being evaluated outside the app context, so you require the following lines

```
'<% url = RailsAppName::Application.routes.url_helpers %>'
console.log '<%= url.root_path %>'
```

A similar question can be found here [Route helpers in asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725629/route-helpers-in-asset-pipeline)

Comment: Ah. I forgot that JS files can go in the views directory too, not just the assets directory.

Comment: In Rails 4, I had to add only_path: true to `url.root_path(only_path: true)` to avoid a default host exception.