# rails route helper with id in js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, routes, asset-pipeline, helper

I'm using Bootstrap with a Rails application.  I want a div with class .container on the home page and all post show pages.  Every other page should have class .container-fluid.  I'm trying to accomplish this with javascript in a js.erb file located in app/assets/javascripts.  If the path is "/" or "/posts/:id" I will remove class .container-fluid and add class .container to id #wrapper else I will remove class .container and add class .container-fluid.  I can't figure out how to do this with all post ids, but I can do it with a specific post id.  I've used [route helpers in the asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725629/route-helpers-in-asset-pipeline) to get this far.  My code below successfully changes the class of post with id 1 to .container.  How would I change any post show page to class .container?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
dashboard.js.erb

function wrapperClass() {
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  <% url = Rails101primer::Application.routes.url_helpers %>
  var root_path = "<%= url.root_path %>";
  var post_path = "<%= CGI.unescape url.post_path(1) %>";
  if (path == root_path || path == post_path) {
    jQuery('#wrapper').removeClass('container-fluid');
    jQuery('#wrapper').addClass('container');
  } else {
    jQuery('#wrapper').removeClass('container');
    jQuery('#wrapper').addClass('container-fluid');
    };
};

jQuery(document).ready( function () {
  wrapperClass();
  jQuery(document).on('page:load', function () {
    wrapperClass();
  });
});
```

Comment: why not apply a unique id on home page and then target that id to apply class?

Comment: #wrapper was the unique id I was using to apply the class changes.  I've decided to scrap the javascript and move forward by adding .container and .container-fluid to the respective views.  It seems not DRY by rails standards, but the javascript is above my skill level.